# Is this a Functional or Non-Functional requirement?

Tags: requirements

I am trying to figure our if the following system requirement is a Functional requirement or a Non-Functional Requirement?

"The Stock Control system must update the stock item quantity when a stock item is sold."

I personally believe that it must be a NF requirement, due to the 'when' part.

please help to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a functional requirement.**

Compare it to the [definition of a functional requirement from Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_requirement)

> A function is described as a set of inputs, the behavior, and outputs.
>
> Functional requirements [...] define **what** a system is supposed to accomplish.

The Wikipedia article describes the difference between functional and non-functional requirements as well.

> Generally, functional requirements are expressed in the form "system must do ", while non-functional requirements are "system shall be "

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the wikipedia definition of NFR, I would say a NFR describes **how** the system (or a specific feature) should behave; while a functional requirement describes **the behaviour itself**.

Other thing you could keep in mind with these definitions is "Is this statment applicable throughout the application?". A requirement that says "The user should be able to sign in" is the behaviour itself - it does not extend other definitions. While "the user should perform any activity in 15 clicks, maximum" is a extension of behaviour that is applicable to other behaviours. The [NFR Framework](http://www.utdallas.edu/~supakkul/tools/RE-Tools/NFR-Framework.html) makes this extension characteristic explicity.

Wikipedia has [a list of NFRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) that may make more clear what is a NFR.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Functional Requirement, 
Clue one: "Must"

Clue two: part of correct working of the system, (if ignored, you will be selling products you dont have in the inventory)

clue three: your other systems like auto re-stock etc wont work without this.

this is so far deep in the functional requirement section, that it is even not visible from the boundary of Functional-Nonfunctional reqs.